# Why are entered numbers repeating in my calculator program?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I press 1 it take 11 , after 1 when i press 2 it will take 122 and the problem keep goes and when i press c ,it will clear acc to the program but after clearing it will print c on it

this works properly on the console but after evaluation(i.e pressing = ) it will give answer then = )

```js
screen = document.getElementById('screen');
buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
screenValue = "";

for (items of buttons) {
  items.addEventListener('click', e => {
    button_text = e.target.innerText;

    if (button_text == 'X') {
      button_text = '*';
      screenValue += button_text;
      screen.value = screenValue;
    } else if (button_text == 'C') {
      screenValue = "";
      screen.value = screenValue;
    } else if (button_text == "=") {
      screen.value = eval(screenValue);
    } else {
      screenValue += button_text;
      screen.value = screenValue;
    }
  })
}

buttons.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  emp = e.key;
  
  if (emp == "C") {
    screenValue = "";
    screen.value = screenValue;
    console.log(emp);
  } else if (emp == "=") {
    screen.value = eval(screenValue);
    console.log(screen.value);
  } else {
    screenValue += emp;
    screen.value = screenValue;
    console.log(screen.value);
  }
})
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <div class="calculator">
      <input type="text" name='screen' id='screen'>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><button>(</button></td>
          <td><button>)</button></td>
          <td><button>C</button></td>
          <td><button>%</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>9</button></td>
          <td><button>8</button></td>
          <td><button>7</button></td>
          <td><button>+</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>6</button></td>
          <td><button>5</button></td>
          <td><button>4</button></td>
          <td><button>-</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>3</button></td>
          <td><button>2</button></td>
          <td><button>1</button></td>
          <td><button>X</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>0</button></td>
          <td><button>.</button></td>
          <td><button>/</button></td>
          <td><button>=</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>


  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with your English. I'm not sure what "it will take" means.

Comment: `buttons.addEventListener` should cause an error. `buttons` is a list, you need to loop over it like you did for `click`.

Comment: Never use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

Comment: I don't get the doubled input when I run the snippet here.

Comment: I think the keydown listener should be on `window`, not `buttons`.

Comment: `document.querySelector("table").addEventListener("click", evt => { if (evt.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {  cost myKey = evt.target.textContent;  })`

Comment: It's because your just adding the 1 as a string.  The first event listener changes the variable to `"1"`, then the second event listener is just adding the string `"1"` to the variable, resulting in `"11"`.

Answer (score 1):

The "buttons" variable created by you is a javaScript Collection. And I think you can`t use addEventListener on a collection. I have corrected the code for you.

```js
let screen = document.getElementById("screen");
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
let screenValue = "";

for (items of buttons) {
    items.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        button_text = e.target.innerText;
        if (button_text == "X") {
            button_text = "*";
            screenValue += button_text;
            screen.value = screenValue;
        } else if (button_text == "C") {
            screenValue = "";
            screen.value = screenValue;
        } else if (button_text == "=") {
            screen.value = eval(screenValue);
            screenValue = eval(screenValue);
        } else {
            screenValue += button_text;
            screen.value = screenValue;
        }
    });
    items.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        emp = e.key;

        if (emp == "C" || emp == "c") {
            screenValue = "";
            screen.value = screenValue;
            console.log(emp);
        } else if (emp == "=") {
            screen.value = eval(screenValue);
            console.log(screen.value);
        } else {
            screenValue += emp;
            screen.value = screenValue;
            console.log(screen.value);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <div class="calculator">
      <input type="text" name='screen' id='screen'>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><button>(</button></td>
          <td><button>)</button></td>
          <td><button>C</button></td>
          <td><button>%</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>9</button></td>
          <td><button>8</button></td>
          <td><button>7</button></td>
          <td><button>+</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>6</button></td>
          <td><button>5</button></td>
          <td><button>4</button></td>
          <td><button>-</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>3</button></td>
          <td><button>2</button></td>
          <td><button>1</button></td>
          <td><button>X</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>0</button></td>
          <td><button>.</button></td>
          <td><button>/</button></td>
          <td><button>=</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>


  </div>
```